# How to limit scope parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want limit scope parameter in my routes.
For example, I have this routes,

```
namespace devices do
 scope :device_type do 
  ..// my routes
 end
end
```

in this i want limit scope parameter

> :devise_type

Only two routes should be is existed

> devices/android
>   devices/ios

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, use `constraints`:

```
namespace :devices do
  scope :device_type, constraints: { device_type: /(android|ios)/ } do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Notice, that you can't and don't need to use `\A`, `^`, `\Z`, and `$`, the whole regexp must match.